# drop duplicates depending on the value in the column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I need to leave the first or last row depending on the value in the in/out column:

if In/Out is 'in'  leave the first row.
if In/Out is 'out' leave the last row

```
Id    Day   Hour  In/Out
1      2     5     in
3      2     5     in
4      2     6     in
4      2     7     in >> remove
1      2     14    out
3      2     14    out
4      2     14    out >> remove
4      2     15    out
1      3     5     in
3      3     5     in
3      3     6     in
4      3     7     in
1      3     14    out
3      3     14    out
4      3     15    out

 df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Id', 'Day', 'Hour', 'In/Out'], inplace=True)

leave all first rows.
```

How to remove duplicates depending on values ​​in a column

Comment: Can you make the example more specific? I don't see in the sample dataframe duplicates by `['Id', 'Day', 'Hour', 'In/Out']`. With "leave" do you mean remove the first row if the value is `In`?

Comment: No,no first row  leave . Other rows remove  if the value is In.           If the value is Out leave last row and remove other.

Answer (score 1):

Not understand your structure but it's an approach ;

```
df_in = df[df["In/Out"] == 'in'].drop_duplicates(subset=['Id', 'Day', 'Hour', 'In/Out'], keep='first')
df_out = df[df["In/Out"] == 'out'].drop_duplicates(subset=['Id', 'Day', 'Hour', 'In/Out'], keep='last')

df_ = pd.concat([df_in,df_out],ignore_index=True)
df_.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: It _seems_ (clarification needed @benek) to me that the first in entry of _a day_ and the last entry of _a day_ is wanted. So you should at least exclude `'Hour'` from the `subset` parameter.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  First in entry of a day if In/Out is 'In' and last entry if In/Out is 'out'. I remove 'Hour' from subset parametr. But I get the results as below, there is always the first entry, even if it is selected keep='last'

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df[-((df['In/Out'] == 'in') & df.duplicated(subset=['Id', 'Day', 'In/Out'], keep='first'))]
    df = df[-((df['In/Out'] == 'out') & df.duplicated(subset=['Id', 'Day', 'We/Wy'], keep='last'))]
    df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

This code works. Drop rows. Why the above code doesn't work. I don't know.
Thanks for help.